# How to disable some drop downs until the first/main drop down is selected?

Tags: javascript

I have 4 drop downs in my form but to display results the "main" dropdown should be selected. So my question is how should I disable all other dropdowns until the user selects an option from that specific dropdown?

```
**main**
<select class="form-control" name="make">
<option><option>
</select>

**others**
<select class="form-control" name="model">
<option><option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="year">
<option><option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="price">
<option><option>
</select>
```

Comment: Give them the `disabled` attribute, and then add some JS to re-enable them when appropriate? Where did you get stuck [when you tried it](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)? Have a look at some of the questions under the "Related" heading on the right.

Answer (score 2):

First disable the 3 drop-down menus.
And then enable them upon changes of the main menu by simple jQuery.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/knY2T/

```
<select class="form-control" name="make">
<option><option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="model" disabled>
<option><option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="year" disabled>
<option><option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="price" disabled>
<option><option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$("select[name='make']").change( function() {
    $("select[name='model']").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("select[name='year']").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("select[name='price']").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you ask for a pure JavaScript answer, and not jQuery or the like :)

```
function validate_main(e) {
    var i, 
        bad = this.value === "please",
        selects = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
    for (i = 0; i < selects.length; ++i) {
        if (selects[i].id !== 'main')
            selects[i].disabled = bad;
    }
}
var sel = document.getElementById("main");
sel.addEventListener("change", validate_main);
```

<kbd>***[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/UwQq8/)***</kbd>

Given e.g. this markup:

```
**main**
<select class="form-control" name="make" id="main">
    <option value="please">please select</option>
    <option value="main">main</option>
</select>

**others**
<select class="form-control" name="model" disabled>
    <option>others1</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="year" disabled>
    <option>others2</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="price" disabled>
    <option>others3</option>
</select>
```

If you like add something [like this](https://gist.github.com/eirikbacker/2864711) as polyfill for *addEventListener* as the method for attaching event differ somewhat between browsers.

You could also use the `onchange` attribute directly in the markup, but that is generally not advised.

Answer (score 0):

add the attr 'disabled' to the "others" select input:

```
<select class="form-control" name="..." disabled>
```

Then, in javascript, do:

```
$('select[name="make"]').on('change', function(){
    $('.form-control').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```